# Hardware for wordpress site?

Tags: web-server

What PC should I buy if I want to host a (relatively) simple wordpress site?
It should be reliable. But I probably do not need an expensive rack, but just a build that would last for ideally several years.

I know I can buy external hosting, but the person that asked me to set it up, does not want his data hosted externally. The site has a lot of data files, but a 500GB disk should solve this.

Comment: It definitely depends on how many users you will have. If you just have a visitor once in a while even a Raspberry Pi could be sufficient...

Comment: Very little users, but should be stable. But is a Raspberry pi reliant enough?

Comment: Well, maybe I was a bit overexaggerating, but most probably a even a Raspberry Pi would be sufficient for this task, and of course also stable enough. Any PC built in the last 15 years should be more than enough. If you are hosting it privately you should definitely care about your internet connection more than about the machine you're hosting it on.